# Python import/insert a CSV (without headers) in a Oracle BD using cx_Oracle

Tags: python-2.7, cx-oracle

Can anyone suggest a way to import a CSV file into a Oracle BD using cx_Oracle. The below code works but I have to manually delete the CSV headers column on row 1 before I run the below Python Script. Is there a way to change the code to ignore line 1 of the CSV file?

```
import cx_Oracle
import csv

connection = cx_Oracle.connect(USER,PASSWORD,'adhoc_serv')#DADs 

cursor = connection.cursor()

insert = """
INSERT INTO MUK (CODE, UNIT_NAME, GROUP_CODE, GROUP_NAME,)
VALUES(:1, :2, :3, :4)"""

# Initialize list that will serve as a container for bind values
L = []

reader = csv.reader(open(r'C:\Projects\MUK\MUK_Latest_PY.csv'),delimiter=',')

for row in reader:
L.append(tuple(row))


# prepare insert statement
cursor.prepare(insert)
print insert 

# execute insert with executemany
cursor.executemany(None, L)

# report number of inserted rows
print 'Inserted: ' + str(cursor.rowcount) + ' rows.'

# commit
connection.commit()

# close cursor and connection
cursor.close()
connection.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to simply ignore line 1 of the CSV file, that is easily accomplished by performing this immediately after the reader has been created:

```
next(reader)
```

This will simply get the first row from the CSV file and discard it.

Comment: your a legend & such a simple solution. Many Thanks